# SQL Main query value used in the WHERE in the subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm really confused by this SQL here, I have this sample where I am using the value from the main query in the subquery and then using XML PATH to add a comma between the dates. The setup is 2 tables one with the dates I want to string together. I am not sure why the subquery where statement is not retuning the correct results.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5443b/2

Setup

```
CREATE TABLE log
    ([logID] [int] NULL, 
     [LogDate] [datetime] NULL
    )
;

CREATE TABLE logdata
    ([logdataID] [int] NULL, 
     [logID] [datetime] NULL
    )
;
    
INSERT INTO log
    ([logID], [LogDate])
VALUES
    (1, 2021-02-01),
    (1, 2021-02-02),
    (1, 2021-02-03),
    (3, 2021-03-12),
    (4, 2021-02-12)
;

INSERT INTO logdata
    ([logdataID], [logID])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3)
;
```

My attempt:

```
Select 
logID,
logdataID
LogDate =  (SELECT ',' + CAST(LogDate AS varchar) FROM log WHERE logID =  logID FOR XML PATH('') )
from logdata
```

Results

```
1,2021-02-01,2021-02-02,2021-02-03,2021-03-12,2021-02-12
2,2021-02-01,2021-02-02,2021-02-03,2021-03-12,2021-02-12
3,2021-02-01,2021-02-02,2021-02-03,2021-03-12,2021-02-12
```

But my desired results would be:

```
1 2021-02-01,2021-02-02,2021-02-03
2 2021-03-12
3 2021-02-12
```

Comment: You forget to add GROUP BY. PS. `WHERE logID =  logID` - seriously? this is the most exotic method to check for NULL...

Comment: Have you considered using [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: You tag the question with [sql-server]. But the fiddle sets SQLite as DBMS... Why?

Comment: *But my desired results would be:* ?? The row (2, 2) in `logdata` have no matched row in `log`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your subquery, `WHERE logID =  logID` is ambiguous. LogID exists in two tables, but the query doesn't tell SQL Server that you intend to use `logID` from one table to join to the `logID` in the other.

In your version of the query, SQL Server is interpreting that within the scope of the subquery only, so that it is using `log.logID = log.logID` which is essentially saying `WHERE 1=1`.

Instead, [always use table aliases & prefix the columns with the table alias](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/16/bad-habits-to-kick-inconsistent-table-aliasing). Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ld.logID,
    ld.logdataID,
    LogDate =  (SELECT ',' + CAST(l.LogDate AS varchar) 
                FROM log AS l 
                WHERE l.logID =  ld.logID 
                FOR XML PATH('') 
               )
FROM #logdata AS ld;
```